# dynamically allow roles to a page or folder

Tags: asp.net, authentication, membership

I am using asp.net webforms. I use a web.config to define what roles can access pages and folders. like this

```
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow roles="Admin" />
       <deny users="*" />
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
```

how can I do this dynamically? so without deploying I could add a role, like 'Developer'

Is there a way I could read these from a database? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly are you asking here...

The authorization sighted by you is known as [URL Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and provided by in-build ASP.NET module. This implementation uses the context associated `IPrincipal` (`HttpContext.User`) to see the authenticated user is member of configured role. So if you want to have your own arbitrary roles (instead of windows roles), you can provide your own `IPrincipal` implementation that would retrieve the assigned roles for the current user from the data-base (or any other source that you want to use). However, the authorization information will still remain in the configuration file.

In case, you want to move the authorization information (who can access what) then you can implement your own authorization module. The module can read this information from the database and enforce the access security the way you wanted.

Comment: Ok, so I am right now just using the asp.net url authorization. If i need it to be dynamic, I would want to implement my own authorization module. thanks for clearing it up.  do you have any tips on how to do the  authorization module?  thanks again

Comment: @eiu165, its straight-forward - implement `IHttpModule` and put authorization logic in/after `PostAuthenticateRequest`. IMO, a authorization module could be very limiting - you can only secure based on request data - which is probably URL and PathInfo (assuming it will very tedious to look at actual request data). For full-fledged security model, you need to secure business resources/actions (at lower layers) - for example, can current use create/update/delete a business entity? can user approve a work-flow? So in my applications, I use a role based security manager at business layer.