# authorization module in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I was wondering if there was an example or a blogpost to show how to do the authorization module in asp.net.

[dynamically allow roles to a page or folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008752/dynamically-allow-roles-to-a-page-or-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net supports Forms Authorization. Here is a good blogpost how to use it: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping that this is best for how to do [authorization](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871) in [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/user-based-authorization-cs) along with authorization ,it will also explains [authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPDOTNETauthentication.aspx) also...